# Mountain Lion Title Bar Truncation

Tags: macos, ui

With OSX Mountain Lion (10.8.2) there is a UI problem.

Calendar + Reminder +  Sticky Note apps have truncated title text

If i login as a guest they are correct. There is clearly a preference somewhere which is causing this but I've got no idea how to fix it.

[image: Irritating title bars]

Comment: Ouch! That’s burning my eyes. Unfortunately, not everything is based on preference files, so this most probably not caused by that. Do any other apps have this problem?

Comment: just these ones that i've seen, the actual apps must be ok i guess given that they're fine in guest mode. aaargh

Comment: Have you tried logging out/restarting? Restarting in safe mode?

Comment: yes i've restarted (well i say restarted; 10.8.2 kernel panics every evening)

Comment: Have you solved this by now? Have you updated to 10.8.3?

Comment: I'm on 10.8.4 and the problem still remains.

Comment: Try creating a new user and transfer your documents to it.

Comment: Is there perhaps something wrong with the fonts in your normal user account?  I think Lucida Grande is used in title bars... perhaps this has become corrupt.

Comment: No, i gave up trying to solve this issue. The fonts idea is good. I'll take a look. Failing that when Mavericks comes out I'll create a new user and move everything across. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The similarities between these three applications is that they all show "Updating..." in the title bar when sending/receiving data. Maybe something related to sync services or Calendar Agent? It might help to [reset sync services](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1627).

Issues that are only occurring within your user account (and not others) are most likely related to preferences or other data inside of that account. A great place to start is the ~/Library/Preferences folder. Performing a [split-half search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troubleshooting) on the contents of that directory is a good way to attack the issues. If the problem doesn't lie within the Preferences folder, there's a good chance that it's in ~/Library somewhere (Calendars?).

If you're lucky, the upgrade to Mavericks won't use the same functionality (i.e., won't read the corrupt preferences)...However, you may still experience the issues in that OS if you install over the top of your current user environment.

Comment: Yep, still broken in Mavericks.. :(